# supervisord process does not reload new php code

Tags: php, supervisord

For synchronous processing, we use supervisord with a beanstalkd queue. The application and worker code is all written in php (using [SlmQueue](http://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmQueue)). I notice that when we deploy new code, the new code isn't working for the worker processes. I am not quite sure what's the reason, but what I did found out:

1. `service supervisor restart` does not restart the process (the PID keeps the same)
2. `supervisorctl reload` does reload all the processes, the new code is used for now
3. `supervisorctl` has no way (as I understand it) to reload only one program and keep the others still running

I am looking for a way to deploy new code (working via ansible and a git checkout) and no need to restart the complete supervisor process with all its children. We run Ubuntu 12.04 machines with PHP 5.5. I guess the opcode cache may play a role, but I am unsure how to trigger a flush for these specific files.

Is there any way to gracefully reload the processes and not completely reload all supervisord child processes? Or if the reason might be the opcode cache, is it possible to flush the cache with a certain trigger?

Answer (score 2):

You can use supervisorctl to restart only one process.

```
supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisord/supervisord.conf
```

Once you are in the supervisor subshell you can use `status` and `restart` to reload your job.
Consider the following example where I reload flower

```
supervisor> status
   beat_worker:beat_worker_00          RUNNING   pid 32274, uptime 0:27:45
   flower                              RUNNING   pid 32275, uptime 0:27:45
   workers:worker_wkrone_00            RUNNING   pid 32278, uptime 0:27:45
   workers:worker_wkrtwo_00            RUNNING   pid 32276, uptime 0:27:45
   workers:worker_wkrthree_00          RUNNING   pid 32277, uptime 0:27:45

supervisor> restart flower
   flower: stopped
   flower: started
```

and now if you do a status again you will see that the pid of `flower` has changed.

```
supervisor> status
   beat_worker:beat_worker_00          RUNNING   pid 32274, uptime 0:28:13
   flower                              RUNNING   pid 32713, uptime 0:00:08
   workers:worker_wkrone_00            RUNNING   pid 32278, uptime 0:28:13
   workers:worker_wkrtwo_00            RUNNING   pid 32276, uptime 0:28:13
   workers:worker_wkrthree_00          RUNNING   pid 32277, uptime 0:28:13
```

Then just do a `ctrl -d` to exit the supervisord shell.
If you inspect the output of status you will see that the pid of the job changed and the uptime count restarted.

Comment: So you have to manually enter in supervisor interactive subshell. I bet OP wants to automate it, thus interactive is not really what he needs.

Answer (score 0):

The supervisorctl that comes with Supervisord 3.0 does allow restarting individual programs (or groups of programs) as a single non-interactive command.

```
# supervisorctl help restart
restart <name>          Restart a process
restart <gname>:*       Restart all processes in a group
restart <name> <name>   Restart multiple processes or groups
restart all             Restart all processes
Note: restart does not reread config files. For that, see reread and update.
```

E.g. `supervisorctl restart my_program` works fine now.

Regarding your related question on how to flush PHP's opcache, the following should help:

A universal way is to create a .php file with the contents:

```
<?php
opcache_reset();
```

Then call that via your webserver, e.g. via `curl https://example.com/flush_cache.php`. It's important to do the `opcache_reset()` call via your webserver in order to flush the right cache. Calling it via the php cli command won't work.

There are some other ways to flush it, depending on the way you run PHP. For Apache with mod_php you can reload Apache via `apachectl graceful` (or similar). For PHP-FPM you can reload the FPM process via `service php-fpm reload` (or similar). Another option is to use [cachetool](http://gordalina.github.io/cachetool/), which allows flushing from the cli without restarting processes and also provides commands to get statistics.